# Is Task.Delay() needed in IAsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, blazor

To get a list as stream in .NET it looks like I need to have Task.Delay(). If I remove it no error is thrown but I get nothing back. Can someone explain the need of Task.Delay?

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetCalendar() {
    if (!deserializer.Any()) {
        deserializer = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, Calendar>>($"date/{year}.json");
    }
    foreach (var key in deserializer.Keys) {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        yield return key;
    }
    NotifyStateChanged();
}
```

The consuming code is this:

```
await foreach (var key in State.GetCalendar()){
    Keys.Add(key);
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

The idea is to receive the list as a stream, instead of waiting to get all the results I am receiving one by one. If I delete Task.Delay() or if I have Task.Delay(0) the page does not load, only works as expected with Task.Delay(number).

Comment: The compiler will cut the method into a statemachine at the position where you placed `await`. But why are you trying to make this method async? The information you return is synchronous . So I think it should be `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`. Like returning the `deserializer.Keys` directly. IAsyncEnumerable is useful when you need to await each item/iteration.

Comment: it should work fine without it; can you show the consuming code? there's no reason that task.delay should make or break this

Comment: I have added more details to the question. @HenkHolterman the nothing back is that the page does not load, it freezes.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I have a big list and because waiting for the entire list takes some time I am retrieving one by one.

Comment: Retreiving one by one will take a _lot_ longer. It just won't be as boring.

Comment: Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem; the current code will not fail if the `Task.Delay` is removed.

Comment: On a broader note, the code is not doing what you think it is doing. There's still only one `await` and it gets back all the items at once. Logically, you have a `Task<IReadOnlyList<string>>`, and converting it into an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` like this isn't going to retrieve items one at a time.